# Text Pattern Recognition - Model building using R

Tags: r, data-mining, pattern-recognition, artificial-intelligence

I have a training dataset which has two columns which has around 70 values.

“PNRNo” whose values like UT767G, CADA, 4I9I59, 4BH5TW…(typical PNR number patterns)
I have created one more factor variable mentioning (IsPNR) – so all the values are 1 (true)
My first objective is to create a model on this training set which would recognize the text pattern.

Second objective: The model would then be used to predict IsPNR with new set of test values like “Anshuk”, “4EL58S”…as 0 and 1…

Which model would be best for recognizing such kind of pattern and having decent accuracy? I tried naiveBayes, but I don’t think it is all doing a good job. Its predicting all the test values as true. I suppose naive Bayes is not meant for this.

Comment: What does the acronym PNR mean?

Comment: @user777 Does it matter, given that typical patterns have been given and the objective has been stated?

Comment: @whuber If those are airline reservation record locator numbers ("PNR numbers"), then the task is basically pointless because they are formed as arbitrary 6-digit alphanumeric combinations (but sometimes 4-digit). Sometimes 0 and O are omitted, or $I$ and 1, so you can just grep for those characters and make a guess.

Comment: @user777 That's a very interesting point!  In principle, then, a good dataset and a good modeling approach should be able to recognize this fact and come up with just as good a solution.  It seems to comes down to whether we want to address the actual problem the OP faces or answer the statistical problem they have posed.  Either way, your clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The feasibility of this task depends on what two kinds of strings you're comparing. If you're comparing PNR numbers (which are formed as arbitrary combinations of numbers and letters) to any arbitrary string, I think you'll be hard pressed to do better than flipping a coin. I've heard it asserted that the set of valid PNRs is smaller than the set of all alphanumeric arbitrary strings of the same length, but I haven't found any reference to that effect. In practice, it's probably true on an airline-by-airline basis that not all combinations are valid because airlines all have their own business practices (caveat: acquisitions and mergers may make this effect nonuniform within airlines). If airline information is known, then you could work on discovering which combinations are/are not invalid and why... Since PNRs are recycled over a long enough time interval, you can just check which patterns never occur in that interval and mark those as invalid.

If you're comparing PNR numbers to natural language (like what a person might send in an e-mail), then you can make a few simple rules that will give you considerable leverage.

1. Check the length of the word. If it's no the length of a PNR number, it's not a PNR number. Likewise if it contains non-PNR characters like @ or $.
2. Check if the word has numbers. If it contains numbers *and* letters, then it's almost assuredly a PNR number.
3. Check the vowel/consonant patterns. Some linguists have characterized the vowel/constonant patterns in languages, so you can leverage that literature here.
4. Check if it's a dictionary word. If it is, it's probably not a PNR-- but at the same time, "SEEING" is a valid PNR (provided the particular reservation system admits $I$), and it is also an English word.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the comments to the question ...

Unless these PNR's are arbitrary alpha-numerics as [user777](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/22311/user777) points out, this seems to be a problem best solved with a Regular Expression.

You mention that all 70 "IsPNR" tags are 1 so you don't have a negative case to train with either, also making machine learning a bad choice.